# Unbalanced Training Data for Machine Learning (CNNs / RNNs)

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I found that while training some CNNs and RNNs on imbalanced training data, that my training converges relatively quickly, with the accuracy being around the percentage of the bigger class (so e.g. if there are 80% yes examples it will probably always output yes). I find that explainable .. that this solution is a local optimum and the network cannot escape it while training. Is this explantion correct and this behaviour thus mostly found in these cases?
What can I do against it? Synthesize more training data to make the set more even? What else?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right. Imbalanced training data do impacts the accuracy. Some of the solutions to come over imbalanced class problem are following:

1) More data collection: This is not easy in some cases. For example, there are a very small number of cases of frauds compared to non fraud cases.

2) Undersampling: Removing the data from the majority class. You can remove it randomly or informative (taking help from the distribution to decide what parts/patches to be removed)

3) Oversampling: Replicating observations belonging to minority class.

Answer (score 1):

Your question has nothing to do with TF, this is a standard problem in machine learning. Just type "dealing with imbalanced data in machine learning" in google and read a few pages.

Here are a few approaches:

- get more data
- use other metric (f1)
- undersampling/oversampling/weighting